# java spring application with c3p0 pool generate java.lang.SQLException : some resource failed to close properly while closing

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

we are using spring with c3p0 as the database pool, we use oracle 10g as the database.
when we launch the application,it continues show following error

```
 2012-5-7 13:12:43 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask run
 Warning: Failed to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@20af46
 java.sql.SQLException: Some resources failed to close properly while closing com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@20af46
  2012-5-7 14:45:51 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection logCloseExceptions
  Info: [c3p0] Exceptions occurred while trying to close a PooledConnection's resources normally.
  2012-5-7 14:45:51 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection logCloseExceptions
  Info: [c3p0] NewPooledConnection close Exception.
  java.sql.SQLException: More data can not be read from the socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:106)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:465)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:1203)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:549)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

 In oracle trace file,we found the following error
  *** 2012-05-07 11:50:56.421
   ksedmp: internal or fatal error  
   ORA-07445: An unexpected error: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [_evaopn2+153] [PC:0x1BBDFA9] [ADDR:0x0] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
   Current SQL statement for this session:
```

Is the oracle error cause the above reason.we take a lot of time to find the problem but we have not found the problem. before we are using oracle 9i,and it did not have the problem.recently we upgrade to oracle 10g.where will be the problem? any idea will be very helpful.thanks!
    the c3p0 we used is com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar.

Comment: you may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error