# ORA-03113 in code. In addition, TNS-12535 and ORA-03137 in alert file

Tags: oracle11g

I've got an exception that contain ORA-03113:

```
(SiPPSS.GetPrintWorkDirectDetail) - ERR:ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel Process ID: 7448 Session ID: 30 Serial number: 9802 ランニング:12110937 プロセス:T855
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel Process ID: 7448
Session ID: 30 Serial number: 9802    場所 Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   場所 Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   場所 Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   場所 Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   場所 System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   場所 SiPPSS.VSireiMeisaiDsTableAdapters.V_SIREI_MEISAITableAdapter.FillByRunningNoAndProcNo(V_SIREI_MEISAIDataTable dataTable, String RUNNING_NO, String PROC_NO) 場所 C:\SVM\trunk\SiPPSSServer\Server\Dao\View\VSireiMeisaiDs.Designer.vb:行 386
   場所 SiPPSS.GetPrintWorkDirectDetail.Execute(BLogicParam param) 場所 C:\SVM\trunk\SiPPSSServer\Server\BLogic\Screen\Printing\Rprt0701\GetPrintWorkDirectDetail.vb:行 105
```

In this case, the oracle alert log as beblow:

---

```
Fatal NI connect error 12170.

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 01-11月-2012 13:50:45
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12535

TNS-12535: TNS: 操作はタイム・アウトしました。
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505

TNS-00505: 操作タイムアウトです。
    nt secondary err code: 60
    nt OS err code: 0
  Client address: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.41.102.53)(PORT=1794))
Thu Nov 01 13:54:17 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1880
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1879 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1880 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1880 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thu Nov 01 13:54:21 2012
Archived Log entry 1118 added for thread 1 sequence 1879 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 14:40:12 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1881
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1880 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1881 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1881 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thu Nov 01 14:40:16 2012
Archived Log entry 1119 added for thread 1 sequence 1880 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 15:27:42 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1882
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 1881 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1882 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1882 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thu Nov 01 15:27:46 2012
Archived Log entry 1120 added for thread 1 sequence 1881 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 16:23:48 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1883
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1882 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1883 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1883 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thu Nov 01 16:23:52 2012
Archived Log entry 1121 added for thread 1 sequence 1882 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 17:05:50 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1884
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1883 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1884 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1884 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thu Nov 01 17:05:55 2012
Archived Log entry 1122 added for thread 1 sequence 1883 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 17:26:52 2012
```

---

```
Fatal NI connect error 12170.

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 01-11月-2012 17:26:52
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12535

TNS-12535: TNS: 操作はタイム・アウトしました。
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505

TNS-00505: 操作タイムアウトです。
    nt secondary err code: 60
    nt OS err code: 0
  Client address: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.41.102.62)(PORT=1286))
Thu Nov 01 17:27:16 2012
```

---

```
Fatal NI connect error 12170.

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 01-11月-2012 17:27:16
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12535

TNS-12535: TNS: 操作はタイム・アウトしました。
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505

TNS-00505: 操作タイムアウトです。
    nt secondary err code: 60
    nt OS err code: 0
  Client address: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.41.102.62)(PORT=1285))
Thu Nov 01 18:08:39 2012
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1885 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1885 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thu Nov 01 18:08:40 2012
Archived Log entry 1123 added for thread 1 sequence 1884 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 19:33:21 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1886
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1885 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1886 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1886 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thu Nov 01 19:33:25 2012
Archived Log entry 1124 added for thread 1 sequence 1885 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 20:32:25 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1887
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1886 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1887 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1887 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thu Nov 01 20:32:29 2012
Archived Log entry 1125 added for thread 1 sequence 1886 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 21:13:07 2012
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1888 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1888 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thu Nov 01 21:13:08 2012
Archived Log entry 1126 added for thread 1 sequence 1887 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 22:00:00 2012
Setting Resource Manager plan SCHEDULER[0x3006]:DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via scheduler window
Setting Resource Manager plan DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via parameter
Thu Nov 01 22:00:00 2012
Starting background process VKRM
Thu Nov 01 22:00:00 2012
VKRM started with pid=32, OS id=4048 
Thu Nov 01 22:00:59 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1889
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1888 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1889 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1889 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thu Nov 01 22:01:03 2012
Archived Log entry 1127 added for thread 1 sequence 1888 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 22:32:36 2012
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1890 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1890 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thu Nov 01 22:32:37 2012
Archived Log entry 1128 added for thread 1 sequence 1889 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 22:33:18 2012
Errors in file d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\trace\siporex_ora_11884.trc  (incident=101313):
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [12333] [8] [49] [50] [] [] [] []
Incident details in: d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\incident\incdir_101313\siporex_ora_11884_i101313.trc
Thu Nov 01 22:33:21 2012
Trace dumping is performing id=[cdmp_20121101223321]
Thu Nov 01 22:40:43 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1891
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 1890 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1891 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1891 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thu Nov 01 22:40:47 2012
Archived Log entry 1129 added for thread 1 sequence 1890 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Thu Nov 01 23:47:30 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1892
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1891 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1892 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1892 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thu Nov 01 23:47:34 2012
Archived Log entry 1130 added for thread 1 sequence 1891 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 00:49:31 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1893
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1892 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1893 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1893 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Fri Nov 02 00:49:35 2012
Archived Log entry 1131 added for thread 1 sequence 1892 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 01:43:12 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1894
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 1893 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1894 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1894 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Fri Nov 02 01:43:17 2012
Archived Log entry 1132 added for thread 1 sequence 1893 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 01:52:51 2012
Errors in file d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\trace\siporex_ora_6124.trc  (incident=101273):
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [12333] [4] [80] [82] [] [] [] []
Incident details in: d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\incident\incdir_101273\siporex_ora_6124_i101273.trc
Fri Nov 02 01:52:54 2012
Trace dumping is performing id=[cdmp_20121102015254]
Fri Nov 02 02:00:00 2012
Clearing Resource Manager plan via parameter
Fri Nov 02 02:43:37 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1895
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1894 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1895 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1895 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Fri Nov 02 02:43:41 2012
Archived Log entry 1133 added for thread 1 sequence 1894 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 04:46:18 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1896
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1895 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1896 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1896 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Fri Nov 02 04:46:22 2012
Archived Log entry 1134 added for thread 1 sequence 1895 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 04:51:41 2012
Errors in file d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\trace\siporex_ora_4048.trc  (incident=101425):
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [12333] [4] [67] [85] [] [] [] []
Incident details in: d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\incident\incdir_101425\siporex_ora_4048_i101425.trc
Fri Nov 02 04:51:44 2012
Trace dumping is performing id=[cdmp_20121102045144]
Fri Nov 02 05:54:44 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1897
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 1896 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1897 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1897 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Fri Nov 02 05:54:48 2012
Archived Log entry 1135 added for thread 1 sequence 1896 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 07:00:34 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1898
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1897 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1898 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1898 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Fri Nov 02 07:00:38 2012
Archived Log entry 1136 added for thread 1 sequence 1897 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 08:32:41 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1899
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1898 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1899 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1899 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Fri Nov 02 08:32:45 2012
Archived Log entry 1137 added for thread 1 sequence 1898 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 09:48:57 2012
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1900 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1900 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Fri Nov 02 09:48:58 2012
Archived Log entry 1138 added for thread 1 sequence 1899 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 10:18:15 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1901
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1900 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1901 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1901 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Fri Nov 02 10:18:19 2012
Archived Log entry 1139 added for thread 1 sequence 1900 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 10:22:58 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1902
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 1901 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1902 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 1902 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Fri Nov 02 10:23:02 2012
Archived Log entry 1140 added for thread 1 sequence 1901 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 10:27:38 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1903
Checkpoint not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 1902 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1903
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 1902 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1903 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 1903 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Fri Nov 02 10:27:45 2012
Archived Log entry 1141 added for thread 1 sequence 1902 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 10:32:27 2012
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1904
Checkpoint not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1903 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 1904
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1903 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO01.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 1904 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 1904 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\SIPOREX\REDO02.LOG
Fri Nov 02 10:32:34 2012
Archived Log entry 1142 added for thread 1 sequence 1903 ID 0xe48db805 dest 1:
Fri Nov 02 10:35:42 2012
Errors in file d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\trace\siporex_ora_15856.trc  (incident=101353):
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [12333] [8] [49] [50] [] [] [] []
Incident details in: d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\incident\incdir_101353\siporex_ora_15856_i101353.trc
Fri Nov 02 10:35:44 2012
Trace dumping is performing id=[cdmp_20121102103544]
```

I don't know main reason of this issue as well as how to fixing it. Please help me.

Comment: I think this might be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/q/7839907/409172

Comment: You should post the contents of the file d:\oracle\diag\rdbms\siporex\siporex\trace\siporex_ora_11884.trc and the corresponding incident file.