# no more data from socket error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We are using **Oracle 11g** as the database. When I try to execute a select query on sqldeveloper I get this error: `no more data from socket`.
my query is:

```
select
first_name,
last_name,
to_char(birth_date,'YYYY') as "date",
state as "ETAT",
null as "number1",
null as "number2",
'R' as "right",
adresse1 as "adresse 1",
adresse2 as "adresse 2",
adresse3 as "adresse 3",
null as "adresse 4",
adresse_cp as "cpostal",
null as "cpostalb",
null as "num_insee",
ville as "ville",
'France' as "pays",
pieces_nb * mobilier as "cont",
null as "field1",
null as "field2",
null as "field3",
null as "field4",
null as "field5",
substr(type,1,1) as "Typ",
null as "field6",
null as "field7",
null as "field8",
null as "field9",
null as "field10",
pieces as "pieces",
null as "piecesb",
null as "surface",
null as "surfaceb",
decode(salaire,'0','P','1','C','2','L','3','L') as "type_salaire",
null as "field11",
decode(residence_id,'0','P','1','S') as "residence",
null as "field12",
null as "Activite",
to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') as "date_fiche",

LEFT OUTER JOIN person ASSIS on (id_person = ident )
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR on (ADDR.ptrsorid = id_adresse and    ADDR.adress_id = 'ADDR1**')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR2 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR2')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR3 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR3')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR*')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR4 on (ptrfield= id_adresse and DDE.adress_id = 'ADDR4**')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR5 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR5')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR6 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR6')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR7 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR7')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR8 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR8')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR9 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR9')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR10 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR10')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR11 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR11')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR12 on (ptrfield = id_adresse and adress_id = 'ADDR12')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR13 on (ptrfield = ident and adress_id = 'ADDR13')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR14 on (ptrfield = ident and adress_id = 'ADDR14***')
LEFT OUTER JOIN address ADDR15 on (ptrfield = ident and adress_id = 'ADDR15')

where hab_ptrfield = ident
and ptrpolid = id_person
and person_pass_id = pas_id
and ptr_id_adresse = 0
and pas_adress_id_work = 'OK'
and ADDR9.sousc = 'YS'
and ADDR9.adress_id = 'R'
and adress_id_societe = 'M'
and to_char(pol_datbirth,'YYYYMMDD') < '20161201'
 order by person_id;
```

When I change the `null` value in the select query to a string 'NULL' and comment the  `to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') as "date_fiche",` I get the expected result.
What's the solution for this error? Is it related to the field's type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No more data to read from socket error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error)

Comment: I 100% guarantee you can find the answer on Google. This is lazy.

Comment: none of the given solution works for me.

Comment: Reconnect. some times is connection problem

Comment: @DevDOS And you think the SO community can provide a solution when you do not give any code sample, background, or information other than the error message?

Comment: @dfundako I added the query. What's wrong with the use of null instead of the string 'NULL' ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the null is not supposed to be problem but you have set and alias to an oracle datatype date. Change it to bdate or something.

i.e.

```
to_char(birth_date,'YYYY') as "bdate",
```