# SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket only occurs when invoking an oracle package

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

The following error only occurs when invoking an oracle package. Hundreds of different functions are invoked without any problem, but sometimes (not always) when this package is invoked the following exception occurs.

```
due to exception [CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{? = call RCREDITO.PQCRESLG0026.FNRECALCULO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket]: org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{? = call RCREDITO.PQCRESLG0026.FNRECALCULO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1142)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1073)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:359)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:263)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.processResultSet(JdbcTemplate.java:1321)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractOutputParameters(JdbcTemplate.java:1279)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1186)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1121)
... 154 more
WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (ConnectionValidator) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@57aeca52[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@584799b0 connection handles=0 lastUse=1491082422691 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@44bb1f17 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@58f64241[pool=jdbc/SCL] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@f77e708[connectionListener=57aeca52 connectionManager=5f5cabf6 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options jndiName=java:/jdbc/SCL] txSync=null]: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1142)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:852)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1890)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1855)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:304)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CheckValidConnectionSQL.isValidConnection(CheckValidConnectionSQL.java:74)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1100)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.checkValid(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:513)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.getInvalidConnections(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:921)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.validateConnections(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:987)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator$ConnectionValidatorRunner.run(ConnectionValidator.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**The oracle package:**

```
    FUNCTION  FNCATALOGO (PA_FIPAISID        RCREDITO.CREDCLIENTEUNICOPEDIDO.FIPAIS%TYPE,
                                                        PA_FICANAL         RCREDITO.CREDCLIENTEUNICOPEDIDO.FICANAL%TYPE,
                                                        PA_FISUCURSAL  RCREDITO.CREDCLIENTEUNICOPEDIDO.FISUCURSAL%TYPE,
                                                         PA_FIFOLIO          RCREDITO.CREDCLIENTEUNICOPEDIDO.FIFOLIO%TYPE)
                                        RETURN  RCREDITO.PATYPES.rcgCursor
  IS
     rcl_CursorSalida        RCREDITO.PATYPES.rcgCursor;
    csl_5                            PLS_INTEGER := 5;
   csl_n1                         NUMBER(1):=-1;
   csl_sysdate                DATE:=SYSDATE;
   csl_user                      VARCHAR2(100):=USER;
   VL_ATRASO              RCREDITO.CLASIFICACTEU.FIDIASATRASOMAX%TYPE;
   VL_DEPTO                 RCREDITO.CLASIFICACTEU.FIDEPTOID%TYPE;
   VL_TIPODEPTO        RCREDITO.CLASIFICACTEU.FIDEPTOID%TYPE;
   VL_TOTAL               NUMBER:=0;
    REGULARIZACIONES ARRAY_REGULARIZACIONES;
    vi number(3):=0;

      CURSOR CUR_REGULARIZACIONES IS (SELECT TPP.FIFOLIO,TPP.FIPLAZO
                                                                           FROM RCREDITO.TACPLANESPAGO  TPP
                                                                        WHERE TPP.FIFOLIO                =TPP.FIFOLIO+csl_0                            
                                                                              AND TPP.FIIDTIPOPLAN IN (CSL_1,CSL_2,CSL_3,CSL_4,CSL_5,CSL_9,CSL_10)
                                                                              AND TPP.FIPAIS               =TPP.FIPAIS+csl_0                            
                                                                              AND TPP.FIIDZONA        =TPP.FIIDZONA+csl_0                            
                                                                              AND TPP.FIREGIONAL     =TPP.FIREGIONAL+csl_0                            
                                                                              AND TPP.FIDEPTOID         =TPP.FIDEPTOID+csl_0
                                                                              AND VL_ATRASO BETWEEN FIDIASATRASMIN AND FIDIASATRASMAX
                                                                               AND FNSTATUS=CSL_1
                                                                               AND FNTIPOCONVENIO=CSL_2);                                     
  BEGIN

  /*OBTENEMOS EL DEPARTAMENTO Y DIAS DE ATRASO DEL CLIENTE*/
            SELECT FIDIASATRASOMAX,FIDEPTOID,FITIPODEPTO
                INTO VL_ATRASO,VL_DEPTO,VL_TIPODEPTO
               FROM RCREDITO.CLASIFICACTEU 
            WHERE FIPAIS           =PA_FIPAISID
                  AND FICANAL       =PA_FICANAL
                  AND FISUCURSAL=PA_FISUCURSAL
                  AND FIFOLIO       =PA_FIFOLIO;

  /*OBTENEMOS EL TOTAL DE PLANES QUE LE CORRESPONDEN AL CLIENTE PARA INICIALIZAR EL ARRAY */
SELECT COUNT(CSL_1)
   INTO VL_TOTAL
   FROM RCREDITO.TACPLANESPAGO  TPP
WHERE TPP.FIFOLIO                =TPP.FIFOLIO+csl_0                            
      AND TPP.FIIDTIPOPLAN IN (CSL_1,CSL_2,CSL_3,CSL_4,CSL_5,CSL_9,CSL_10)
      AND TPP.FIPAIS               =TPP.FIPAIS+csl_0                            
      AND TPP.FIIDZONA        =TPP.FIIDZONA+csl_0                            
       AND TPP.FIREGIONAL     =TPP.FIREGIONAL+csl_0                            
       AND TPP.FIDEPTOID         =TPP.FIDEPTOID+csl_0
       AND VL_ATRASO BETWEEN FIDIASATRASMIN AND FIDIASATRASMAX
       AND FNSTATUS=CSL_1
       AND FNTIPOCONVENIO=CSL_2;

/*Inicializamos el array de regularizaciones*/
  REGULARIZACIONES:= ARRAY_REGULARIZACIONES();
  REGULARIZACIONES.EXTEND(VL_TOTAL);

         /*POR CADA PLAN QUE APLIQUE PARA EL CLIENTE SE APLICAN LOS RESPECTIVOS CALCULOS*/   
            FOR CUR_TACPLANES IN CUR_REGULARIZACIONES
              LOOP
                        vi:=vi+csl_1;
                        REGULARIZACIONES(vi):=FNCALCULO(PA_FIPAISID,PA_FICANAL,PA_FISUCURSAL,PA_FIFOLIO,CUR_TACPLANES.FIFOLIO,csl_n1);
              END LOOP;

              OPEN rcl_CursorSalida FOR
               SELECT    FIPAISID                                                       AS FIPAIS,
                                FICANAL                                                         AS FICANAL ,
                                FISUCURSAL                                                  AS FISUCURSAL ,
                                FIFOLIO                                                          AS FIFOLIO,
                                FOLIOWEB                                                      AS FW ,
                                IDPLAN                                                            AS FIFOLIOPLAN,
                                PLAZO                                                              AS RPLAZO,
                               DIASPROMESA                                               AS fidiaspromesa ,
                               TIPOPP,
                                TIPOCONVENIO                                            AS RTIPOCONV,
                                TIPOPLAN                                                        AS RPLAN,
                                TIPODEPTO                                                     AS  FISEGMENTO,
                                PORENGANCHEMINIMO                               AS  FIENGANCHEMINIMO,
                                PAGOSUGERIDO ,
                                PAGOREQUERIDO ,
                                SALDOATRASADO                                         AS RSALDOATRASADO,
                                CAPITALATRASADO                                      AS RSALDOXDEVENGAR  ,
                                 INTERESDEVENGADO                                  AS  RINTERESATRASADO,
                                 MORATORIOS                                                 AS RMORATORIOS,
                                 DEVENGOSEMANAL                                       AS RABONOSEMANAL, 
                                 TOTALBONIFICACIONES                              AS RBONIFICACIONES,
                                  BONIFICACIONMORATORIOS                   AS RBONIFMORATORIO,
                                  PORBONIFICACIONMORATORIOS ,
                                  BONIFICACIONINTERESDEVENGADO    AS RBONIFINTERES,
                                  PORBONIFINTERESDEVENGADO               AS RPORCBONIFINTERES,
                                  PAGOPUNTUALPLAN                                     AS RPAGOPUNTUAL ,
                                  ATRASADOMASPP                                         AS RSALDOATRASADOCONBONIF ,
                                  DEVENGODURANTEPLAN                             AS RBONIFDEVENGOSEM,
                                   PAGOINICIALCALCULO ,
                                   PAGOSEMANALCALCULO                             AS PAGOSEMANALPLAN,
                                   PAGOSEMPUNTUALCALCULO                      AS RPAGOSEMPUNTUALPLAN,
                                   PAGOSEMANALATRASADOCALCULO        AS RPAGOSEMATRASADO,
                                   PAGOTOTALCALCULO,
                                   PAGOTOTALREONDEADO,
                                   PAGOINICIAL                                          AS RPAGOINICIAL ,
                                   PAGOSEMANAL,
                                   SALDOAPAGARATRASADO ,
                                   SALDOAPAGARPUNTUAL,
                                   SALDOAPAGAR                                         AS RSALDOXPAGAR,
                                  SALDOTOTALMORAS ,
                                  SALDOTOTAL                                            AS RFNSALDO,
                                 SALDOPORDEVENGAR ,
                                  CAPITALPORDEVENGAR ,
                                  INTERESPORDEVENGAR ,
                                  INTERESESPORDEVENGARPLAZO ,
                                  CAPITALPORDEVENGARPLAZO ,
                                  BONIFICACIONINTERESPORDEVENGAR ,
                                  TOTALBONIFICACIONES ,
                                  SALDOAPAGARMORATORIOS ,
                                  SALDODEVENGODURANTEPLAN ,
                                   SALDOCAPITALPORDEVENGAR
                 FROM TABLE(REGULARIZACIONES);
                 RETURN rcl_CursorSalida;
    EXCEPTION WHEN 
        OTHERS THEN
           RCREDITO.SPREGISTRAERROR (SYSDATE, SQLCODE, SQLERRM, 'PQCRESLG0029');
                   OPEN rcl_CursorSalida FOR
                                    SELECT   csl_0                                                   AS FIIDMENSAJE,
                                                    'Ocurrio un error en la aplicacion' AS FCMENSAJE
                                   FROM DUAL;
                      RETURN rcl_CursorSalida;
  END FNCATALOGO;
```

Spring's StoredProcedure class is used for invocation of functions. Access is via a webservice REST (RestController) with BASIC authentication.

The jdbc driver used is ojdbc7.jar than the official version for Oracle 12 and Java 7.

Java code

```
    private class Function extends StoredProcedure {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List execWithReturnCursor(String functionName, Map<String,Object> inputs) {

        logger.info("INICIANDO EJECUCION DE FUNCION");

        setDataSource(dataSource);
        setFunction(true);
        setSql(functionName);

        if(getOutput() == null && getMapper() != null) {
            super.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR, getMapper()));
        }
        else {
            super.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(getOutput())));
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : inputs.entrySet()) {
            Object value = inputs.get(entry.getKey());
            LOGGER.debug("Parametro {} ",entry.getKey());
            LOGGER.debug("Valor {} ",value);
            super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(entry.getKey(), OracleStoreProcedure.getType(value)));
        }

        compile();
        String fn = functionName+"("+inputs+")";

        //LOGGER.info(fn);
        try {
            Map resultado = super.execute(inputs);
            return (List) resultado.get("cursor");
        }
        catch(Throwable seq){
            logger.info("Ocurrio un problema al invocar la funcion{}", seq);
            return new ArrayList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also include the code you are using to make the call from Java.

Comment: `No more data to read from socket` mean that your connection has been terminated on the other end. Under no circumstances will the database terminate a connection on a function call for you. It could be an interruption in the network itself and TCP terminating your connection but it could also be an issue on the database itself, causing it to drop the connection. If you do have access to the database, look at the alert log for errors. It's usually located under `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<DBName>/<SID>/trace/alert_<SID>.log`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error): it seems very similar to yours. It says that a possible solution can be either

- upgrading the oracle or
- setting oracle parameter _optim_peek_user_binds = false