# Error on login with Oracle Database: no more data to read from socket

Tags: oracle, tomcat7, oracle12c

My scenario: we are migrating from a websphere server to a Tomcat7 server. 
Right now we have in parallel both of them running because we wanted to test first with just a few users if everything works good on P. Both applications point to the same Oracle12c database.

After one week with no issues, suddenly after the weekend users were not able to login anymore. This also happened in our Q instance where just a couple of users were testing some other new issues. This made me think that it may be due to some maintenance work on the Oracle server... but I am not sure here.

I found this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error) with some useful information and I think it may be due to multiple connections to the Oracle database. I would like to know if anyone of you have experienced something like this before in a similar case with two applications pointing to the same Database.

In my case, what would be the proper approach on Oracle to allow multiple connections if that is my problem? I would like to check if that is the issue.

And why did I get this issue after a few days and not some minutes/hours after I deployed the application on P/Q?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
HTTP Status 500 - could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet

type Exception report

message could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:142)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:295)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:173)
            com.bosch.commons.security.providers.ldap.UserServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(UserServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:30)
            org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197)
            org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
            com.bosch.gam.commons.security.GamLdapAuthProvider.authenticate(GamLdapAuthProvider.java:52)
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
            org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
            org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
            org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
            org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
            org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl$3.doInHibernate(UserDaoImpl.java:180)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl$3.doInHibernate(UserDaoImpl.java:1)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:295)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:173)
            com.bosch.commons.security.providers.ldap.UserServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(UserServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:30)
            org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197)
            org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
            com.bosch.gam.commons.security.GamLdapAuthProvider.authenticate(GamLdapAuthProvider.java:52)
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1200)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:861)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
            org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
            org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
            org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
            org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
            org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
            org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl$3.doInHibernate(UserDaoImpl.java:180)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl$3.doInHibernate(UserDaoImpl.java:1)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:295)
            com.bosch.gam.integration.dao.UserDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:173)
            com.bosch.commons.security.providers.ldap.UserServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(UserServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:30)
            org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197)
            org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
            com.bosch.gam.commons.security.GamLdapAuthProvider.authenticate(GamLdapAuthProvider.java:52)
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
            org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
```

Comment: Did you check your alert? Please check there for any oracle internal error and inform me.

Comment: What is an alert? I do not have access to the Oracle server but I could ask to that team.

Comment: oracle database alert log. alert_dbname.log.