# NiFi to fetch huge amount of data from oracle failing

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

We are using NiFi to pull data from oracle and perform some transformation. The pipeline works fine for small amount but fails with the error no output to read from socket when data volume is high -> 1million records.
Any Help or configuration changes that i need to do.

Comment: provide the error stacktrace, the flow, which processors you are using, which processor is failing...

Comment: Hi The ExecuteSql Processor is failing with error message: no more data to read from socket after running for almost an hour. 

ExecuteSql is the first processor which is running select * from {tablename}

Comment: This might be an issue on the Oracle side. This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error

Comment: Can you tell us what release of oracle and the version of NiFi or HDF you are working with?

Comment: Hi, The nifi version is 1.6.0 and oracle 11g.