# DB Connection breaks for my Java application

Tags: java, oracle

My application is fetching data from Oracle DB, but after some time connection breaks.
Getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:456)
```

Comment: more details would be needed about how connection is created, query being run & how result set is extracted etc .

Comment: Looks something to do with installation , [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error)

Comment: Or with an unstable network. Anyhow, what do you use to supervise and reestablish connections?