# There is no more data to read in the socket Oracle 11.0.2.0.1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Good Morning,
I have an issue with oracle,
i have a centos 6.4 virtual machine with oracle 11.2.0.1.0 installed in it.
when I execute my query using sqldeveloper i get the follownig error.

```
There is no more data to read in the socket
```

my query is little bit large i have something like.

```
select columnA, columnB, .....
From View1
left outer join View2
left outer join table1
```

my first view contains 20 left outer joins and 10 inner joins between tables
my seconde view contains a lot of calculated columns with `case when` and even subquerys
and 15 left outer joins and 3 inner joins.

i can't modify this views and i have to test my query.
is there something to do so i can test my query?

Comment: Please read the answer to the question I've linked to in the comment above, it should help you with troubleshooting. Unfortunately, this error may be caused by an Oracle bug ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error), [2](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_no_more_data_to_read_from_socket.htm)), in this case, you'll have to upgrade to Oracle 11.2 or 12.

Comment: I followed [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501129/9266093) and i'm able to test my query.
thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No more data to read from socket error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error)