# After DB server restart - No more data read from socket Error

Tags: java, oracle12c, spring-jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp, tomcat8.5

Spring rest webservice application is able to fetch the data from DB. But getting 'no more data read from socket error' after restart the DB server.. Details are:
JDK 1.8x
Spring JDBC Template & Spring Rest Web service
Oracle 12x
Tomcat 8.x
**Common DBCP 1.4**

The below connection properties that are configured

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">

<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl"/>
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>

<property name="maxActive" value="50"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
<property name="testOnBorrow" value=true/>
<property name="testWhileIdl" value=true/>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value=15000/>
<property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value=50/>
<property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value=300000/>

<property name="Oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=20000;oracle.net.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=20000;oracle.net.encryption_client=REQUESTED"/>
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1142)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1869)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
... 63 more
```

Tried this option `driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` and getting the same socket error.

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does any answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error/7844985 help ?

Comment: No.It was not resolved my error.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-deploy the web service application on tomcat. This will resolve the issue

Comment: this could be a comment.