# WSO2 IS Custom user store - SQLException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we have created a custom user store to connect oracle db for user authentication and it is working fine with registered service provider but sometimes user authentication fails with below error. 
Again after couple of retries it allows and authenticates successfully. Kindly advise

Resident Identity provider details
[image]

Service Provider details

[image]

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-05 05:45:02,752] [30df5237-c271-4dd7-8d3d-a119c6540b26] ERROR {org.wso2.r2.user.store.manager.R2CustomUserStoreManager} - R2CustomUserStoreManager-doAuthenticate: SQLException: No more data to read from socket
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-05 05:45:02,754] [30df5237-c271-4dd7-8d3d-a119c6540b26]  WARN {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection} - Unable to clear Warnings, connection will be closed. java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.clearWarnings(PhysicalConnection.java:2573)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.clearWarnings(PooledConnection.java:813)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.returnConnection(ConnectionPool.java:937)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:100)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.closeConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:948)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(DatabaseUtil.java:999)
    at org.wso2.r2.user.store.manager.R2CustomUserStoreManager.doAuthenticate(R2CustomUserStoreManager.java:156)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticateInternal(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:705)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticateInternalIteration(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:573)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.access$100(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:95)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$4.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:551)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$4.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:548)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticate(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:548)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticateInternal(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:740)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticateInternalIteration(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:573)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.access$100(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:95)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$4.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:551)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$4.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:548)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticate(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:548)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$3.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:531)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$3.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:523)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.authenticate(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:523)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(BasicAuthenticator.java:333)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator.process(BasicAuthenticator.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:502)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:476)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:175)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.GraphBasedSequenceHandler.handle(GraphBasedSequenceHandler.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:239)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter.doFilter(CaptchaFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Regarding to the article [1] there might be an issue in the Oracle side. Could you please check on that?

[1] http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_no_more_data_to_read_from_socket.htm#:~:text=The%20%22no%20more%20data%20to,of%20a%20TNS%20connectivity%20issue.&text=The%20%22no%20more%20data%20to%20read%20from%20socket%22%20error%20is,the%20latest%20release%20of%20Oracle

Comment: This link also might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error