# Oracle 12 error using json blob Column : No more data from read socket

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, apache-camel

I am saving information that comes from a kafka topic in an oracle 12c table that contains a blob type column with the restriction that it is a json, to do this I use apache camel and jpa. After 9 days of running in production I got the following error every time I want to update a record:

```
[WARN][2021-12-04 02:24:03.283][Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - KafkaConsumer[queue-tickets]][SqlExceptionHelper]SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000
[ERROR][2021-12-04 02:24:03.283][Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - KafkaConsumer[queue-tickets]][SqlExceptionHelper]No more data to read from socket
[WARN][2021-12-04 02:24:03.311][Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - KafkaConsumer[queue-tickets]][DefaultErrorHandler]Failed delivery for (MessageId: E1252DFC6750525-00000000000B1B41 on ExchangeId: E1252DFC6750525-00000000000B1B41). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.save(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.tdp.failure.service.FailureService.save(FailureService.java:31) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ObjectHelper.invokeMethodSafe(ObjectHelper.java:372) ~[camel-support-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:493) ~[camel-bean-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:315) ~[camel-bean-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:285) ~[camel-bean-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:146) ~[camel-bean-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:81) ~[camel-bean-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultInstrumentationProcessor.process(DefaultInstrumentationProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-management-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:714) [camel-core-processor-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:623) [camel-core-processor-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) [camel-base-engine-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) [camel-base-engine-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) [camel-core-processor-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:312) [camel-base-engine-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) [camel-base-engine-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) [camel-support-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.doRun(KafkaConsumer.java:349) [camel-kafka-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:214) [camel-kafka-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3493) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3769) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:676) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:119) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:910) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3865) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3845) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3493) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3769) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:676) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
```

When I execute a delete on the table using SQL developer I also get a similar error

```
Error en la línea de comandos : 1 Columna : 1
Informe de error -
Error SQL: No hay más datos para leer del socket
```

In jpa I am using this https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types to save information in json format. The table has a partition of type range by days, I have no errors when an insert is executed.

I need your help to know why this error occurs and how to solve it, please. I request the logs from the database to the dba but it tells me that there are no errors.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error

Comment: I tried the solutions shown in the link, but the error is still present. I will change the blob column to clob, since if I can make updates that do not involve the blob column, it appears to be a problem with the blob column. Thank you.